# Laravel controller return model instance instead data content

Tags: laravel, model, routes, controller

i have this route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'comments', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function(){
    Route::delete('/delete/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'destroy'])->name('comment.delete');
});
```

in my controller i have

```
public function destroy(Comments $comments)
    {
        dd($comments);
    }
```

normally i must have the data of respective of the id right? but instead i got empty instance of the model
[image: like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work you need to change route parameter from `id` to `comments`

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or
> controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route
> segment name.

```
Route::delete('/delete/{comments}', [CommentController::class, 'destroy'])->name('comment.delete');
```

Read here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding.